# deploy .net code using cruise control .net and clear case 7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, cruisecontrol.net, clearcase

What is the method I should use for Extracting,Testing,Compiling,Deploying an ASP.NET (.NET 3.5) application from Clear Case 7.0.
I am new to .net technology and using visual studio 2008 Professional Edition .currently using thick client Clear case dynamic view

1/ Which View I should use for pulling the data from ClearCase:
Dynamic View or Snap shot view?

2/ I would like to pull the latest source from ClearCase and put the source to a specified folder on the server side. based on the config spec.
I started using the Cruise control .net for pulling the source from ClearCase dynamic view.
But it failed with an error `'c:/setup/vtproject/abc is not a snapshot view'` , If so what should be in my ccnet config?

3/ Once the objects are copied, and run a build script to compile the objects and build release version with a release label, deploy the release version into the app server folder(s)

Please suggest me a tool/ solution to setup

Comment: Just added some question in my comments below

Answer (score 0):

> 1/ Which View I should use for pulling the data from ClearCase

You can start with a dynamic view, since it will allow to fiddle with the config spec, until you see exactly the data you need. Then you will switch to a snapshot view.

The config spec content depends on which branch you have store your data (here an ASP.Net application).
If you are not using UCM, but just Base ClearCase, and have not modified any config spec, they are store by default in the **main** branch.
Meaning the default config spec is enough:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/LATEST
```

You can then declare a snapshot view with the same config spec lines plus one: a load rule (`load /myVob/MyRootDirectory`), kind of directive you will not find in a dynamic view since they are... dynamic ;) (they do not "load" anything but give you a network access to the right versions)

---

2/ I would like to pull the latest source from ClearCase and put the source to a specified folder on the server side

Since cruise control complains about a snapshot view, that means you must have ClearCase on the server (not always a good policy, but I am just answering your question).
If you do have ClearCase there, just declare another snapshot view with:

- the same config spec as the one mentioned before
- the root directory of the snapshot view as expected by cruise control ('c:/setup`', supposing '`vtproject`' is a Vob and '`abc`' the root directory of your ASP.Net project)

---

3/ The deployment has nothing to do anymore with ClearCase. Some rsynch or robocopy process is in order at this point.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt advice.could you please give me an example the way you decribed for solution  step1 and step 2

Comment: @cheria: for that, I should to know a bit more of your context, and first, if you are using UCM or not (if not, do you store all files in /main or /main/anotherBranch)? Then I will illustrate... tomorrow;) (almost midnight here)

Comment: I am using clear case baseline not UCM.I am storing the .net files in Main branch for production releases, and sub branch(s) for developement and uat.also vtproject is my vob.I also created a snapshot view called vs2008_v1.